# Angular Directive Scope vs. img src

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive

It seems that the scope object of an angular directive "cripples" `img src` in my case. If I take off `scope: { myDirectiveText: "=" }`, the image will show. With it, the image doesn't show.

Here is the directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
     return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope: { myDirectiveText: "=" }, // having this will cause image to disappear.
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {}
     };
});
```

Here is my the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="anObject in myObjectsFromController">
   <img my-directive my-directive-text="'my text'" ng-src="{{ anObject.ImageUrl }}" />
</div>
```

So, the images are generated from a surrounding `ng-repeat`. Whether I use `ng-src` or just plain `src`, it doesn't matter. If `my-directive` has the scope "property" specified, the image doesn't show. Whether myDirectiveText is =, &, or @ doesn't matter - the image will still not show.

I had the impression that an attribute directive won't affect other attributes of the element it's specified in. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an isolate scope problem. Once you define `scope` as a hash in your directive, all attributes on the element with your directive are now using the same isolated scope as your directive so `ng-src` no longer has access to `anObject`, which is in the parent scope.

Sometimes the easiest options is to split the directives onto two separate elements, with the isolate scope being on the inner element. In your case I think that just using `$parent.anObject.ImageUrl` in the binding is easiest.

Normally properties on the parent scope (from `ng-repeat`) would be accessible without this through prototypical inheritance of the scopes. An isolate scope doesn't have this inheritance, so you need to explicitly use `$parent` to access it's properties.